# Give an example of an infinite non-commutative ring R with char(R)=15

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know I need to use matrices, but I'm not sure how.  I know matrices are non-commutative however I'm confused about the characteristic part.

Comment: There is already an answer addressing your question about characteristic.

Answer (score 4):

$$M_{2} (\mathbb{Z}/(15)[t])$$

Answer (score 1):

The "universal" example of a non-commutative ring is $\mathbb{Z}\langle x,y\rangle$, the ring of "polynomials" or better "words" in $x$,$y$ where $xy$ is not supposed to be $yx$. Thus, we cannot simplify $xyxyx$ for example, it is already in reduced form. The universal example of a ring of characteristic $n$ is $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$. Now guess what the universal example of a non-commutative ring of characteristic $n$ is, and observe that it is infinite (when $n \neq 1$).

Another example: Take any infinite non-abelian group $G$ and consider the group ring $\mathbb{Z}/(15)[G]$.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the set of endomorphisms of sequences with values in $\mathbb Z / 15 \mathbb Z$:

$$R = \mathcal L\left(\left(\mathbb Z / 15 \mathbb Z\right)^\mathbb N\right)$$

Comment: Endomorphisms in which category?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg : Vector spaces.

Comment: Ok, you mean abelian groups. (There is no field over which the abelian group $\mathbb{Z}/15$ is a vector space.)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg : $\mathbb Z/15\mathbb Z$-modules then.